# E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate --- Debian Server

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, debian-wheezy

## apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-fastcgi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate

======/etc/apt/source.list========================

```
deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian wheezy main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian wheezy main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src htp://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

deb htp://ftp.es.debian.org/debian testing main
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian testing main
```

=====================================================

I tried with:
 apt-get update
 apt-get upgrade
 apt-get -b source libapache2-mod-fastcgi

I don't know what happened. Could somebody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That package is in the non-free, but your sources list looks wrong, you've got multiple sources on the same line and 'hxxp' instead of 'http'.  With that as your sources.list you will get errors with apt-get update (which should indicate your problem).

Create the /etc/apt/sources.list file with just the following:

```
deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Re-run 'apt-get update' and then you should be able to install with 'apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi'